# ViewStub vs View.GONE vs Inflate vs ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I've a question related to lazily loading a views / layout performance.
Sometimes we want to dynamically show / hide multiple view. In this case, we have four options:

1. Include all layout in .xml and use setVisibility method (like View.GONE and VIEW.VISIBLE)
2. Using a ViewFlipper / ViewSwitcher
3. Using a ViewStub
4. Programmatically inflating new layouts.

Which one has the best performance?
I've been Googling around and found that ViewStub is specifically designed for that, but I'm not sure about it. Maybe I was wrong or maybe there's even a fifth option that I didn't know. Do you have different opinion or experience related to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's depending on the view you want to inflate itself. Every method you mentioned has it's own overhead and you need to decide where to compromise.

1. If your view is quite simple and doesn't need to initialize much, just set it so `View.GONE`. If it's quite complex or a layout better don't do so.
2. The `ViewFlipper` and `ViewSwitcher` are intended to animate between different views. Its purpose isn't to show and hide a single view. Use it if you have different views to display in the same place at different times.
3. `ViewStub` is just a placeholder which replaces itself with a more complex layout.
4. Doing everything manually is like using `ViewStub` just without having the layout information. If you have the need to create or setup the view programmatically, this might be a good choice though.

Answer (score 6):

In 2017, Android team published AsyncLayoutInflater on support library v24. In 2020, it's part [of Jetpack library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater).

AsyncLayoutInflater is another way to inflate layout lazily. As the API documentation says

> Helper class for inflating layouts asynchronously. To use, construct
> an instance of AsyncLayoutInflater on the UI thread and call
> inflate(int, ViewGroup, OnInflateFinishedListener). The
> AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener will be invoked on the
> UI thread when the inflate request has completed.
>
> This is intended for parts of the UI that are created lazily or in
> response to user interactions. This allows the UI thread to continue
> to be responsive & animate while the relatively heavy inflate is being
> performed.

This is the code snippet to use AsyncLayoutInflater:

```kotlin
button.setOnClickListener { view ->
    val container = findViewById(R.id.container)
    val asyncLayoutInflater = AsyncLayoutInflater(this@MainActivity)
    asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.view_sample,
        container,
        object : OnInflateFinishedListener() {
            fun onInflateFinished(view: View, resId: Int, parent: ViewGroup) {
                parent.addView(view)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@gajendratwinwal/asynclayoutinflater-android-performance-e2fd3e0f908b it also should be considered.

Comment: I thought plain old LayoutInflaters could be initialized lazily without issues... at least RecyclerViews had been doing that for a long time.
Maybe this is combining the oneShotPreDrawListener into a single object or something like that...

I don't understand why they never did any component that handles view state via adapters for reified types.

mutableContainer.set(adapter);

where adapter is: Adapter<MyEnum> adapter = Adapter.get((inflater, myEnum) -> { //returns aView});

So that we could swap and control views via the adapter...

Comment: Hmm... nvm now I noticed it does a "back and forth" (from background to foreground thread) management. something that wouldn't be that hard to achieve if their ArchTaskExecutor class could handle this scenarios IMO, something achievable in a single method,... does it handle backpressure drop tho??